# RestSharp demorando a fazer a primeira requisição

Tags: c#, api, rest, xamarin, restsharp

Eu estou fazendo um aplicativo usando Xamarin Native e resolvi usar o RestSharp pra fazer as requisições a minha API, o problema é que a primeira requisição feita demora alguns segundos (uns 3) para ser feita, já as outras vão rápidas (questão de ms). 
Já tentei diversos "fixes" da comunidade internacional mas nenhum funcionou, segue o código do meu constructor:

```
        public RestApi(IPresenter presenter)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            _server = "http://192.168.29.3";
            #endif
            _client = new RestClient(_server);

            _client.Proxy = null;
            HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
            ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;

            _presenter = presenter;
        }
```

A chamada a api está sendo realizada de forma assíncrona da seguinte forma:

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, method, DataFormat.Json);
_client.ExecuteAsync(request, back => _presenter.HandleData(back));
```

*OBS: Não é problema na API pois o antigo app, feito em java, funciona normalmente.

Comment: Você já fez a requisição na mão ... com WebRequest pra ver se tem diferença?

Comment: Não fiz, fiz apenas pelo Java como eu falei e foi de boa. Pra contornar o problema fiz uma requisição "ping-pong", mas sei que há uma forma "correta" de resolver isso.

Comment: A forma correta é fazer webrequest ... Porque dessa forma está fazendo por um.pacote de terceiros. A sua pergunta deveria ter um.exemplo mínimo e funcional pra verificar o problemas

Comment: Eu consegui melhorar um pouco o tempo de resposta configurando o UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing do RestClient para true.

`_client.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;`

Comment: Fiz uma client simples usando HttpClient e ficou bem mais rápido...